# "Syntax Error: System Events got an error: Automator is not allowed assistive access" for Miniaturise all windows with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator, ui

When I try to Miniaturise all windows with the following AppleScript, Automator minimizes all windows, then tells me: "Syntax Error: System Events got an error: Automator is not allowed assistive access" while I already checked Automator in Security & Privacy > Accessibility > Privacy. Saving the Apple script as an app led to a similar issue (screenshots are attached). **What is the solution to avoid these errors?**

**Apple script**

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to set the value of ¬
    attribute "AXMinimized" of every window of every process ¬
    to true
end
```

**Automator**

[image: Automator Error]

[image: Automator Permission]

**App**

[image: App Error]

[image: App Permission]